# Button in Gridview showing UpdateProgress on Click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, updateprogress

I have a gridview that has many columns within an UpdatePanel, 2 of those columns that are populated with buttons. There is a "Update" button outside of the gridview. When the user clicks "Update", there is a UpdateProgress div that shows up, which is expected. However, when the buttons in the gridview are clicked, it also shows up, which is not what I am intending. How can I exclude these buttons from the UpdateProgress if the gridview itself is in the UpdatePanel? I've tried ChildrenAsTriggers=False and UpdateMode=Conditional but doesn't help. See code being used below.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress id="UpdateProgress" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
        <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" AlternateText="Updating PO, please wait ..." ToolTip="Updating PO, please wait ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:45%;left:50%;" />
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateButton" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>

<ContentTemplate>
<!-- Gridview is here -->

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Example of what's in the gridview:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Button Column One">
            <HeaderStyle Width="70px" />
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="70px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnG" runat="server" OnCommand="btnG_Command" Text="View"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Drug Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnA" runat="server" OnCommand="btnA_Command" Text="View" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: remove that eventName="click" and try

Comment: ControlID="UpdateButton"  only give ID of button u want to onclick progressbar on

Answer (score 1):

Put your Gridview in a separate update panel and specify AssociatedUpdatePanelID field for UpdateProgress control.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress id="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelForButton">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
        <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" AlternateText="Updating PO, please wait ..." ToolTip="Updating PO, please wait ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:45%;left:50%;" />
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelForButton" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateButton" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>

<ContentTemplate>
<!--Button goes here-->

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I don't think this works. The buttons are INSIDE the gridview, and the Update button is completely separate. I DO want the loading screen to show up when the user clicks Update, that's why the gridview is in that UpdatePanel. My problem is that the loading screen is showing up when the buttons IN the gridview are clicked, and I do not want this.